# Security considerations when allowing .swf uploads/embeds

Tags: php, file-upload, flash, xss

In terms of the file upload side I have implemented the common practices (i.e. checking the file size, validating the extension - ensuring it is infact a .swf, when saving the file renaming it entirely to a random alphanumeric id).

Is there anything else I could do/am I missing anything?

Although I have not seen any....could this be dangerous to my visitors (who view the flash) - if so is there a way to migitate?

Comment: flash has very rich and powerful browser scripting abilities. If you allow visitors to upload flash files that will be embedded into your webpages, you're giving them some very extreme power. This is like the ultimate cross site scripting opportunity.

Comment: @rambocoder is there any way of preventing this or atleast migitating it, I've read alot of articles on cross site scripting in the past but most never covered flash (or were very vague)...theres quite a few flash gaming sites out there who operate on a similar basis, as in allow visitor uploads and then display those uploads for the rest to see/play (so I'm guessing there may be some sort of solution to this problem).

Comment: Are you loading the swf file in your page or you are just uploading them ???

Comment: If the page in which the content is embedded is served from a domain used *solely* for that purpose, then any XSS compromise will be contained within that domain (ergo carries reduced risk).

Comment: @Baba both, once an .swf file is uploaded it can be viewed/played (it is embeded on a 'view' page).

Comment: @user962026 don't every do that .... it would be used to attack your clients and you would lose their trust

Comment: @Baba wondering how flash gaming sites manage to do this then?

Comment: @user962026 they create a sandbox http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e3f.html and not sure with the details

Comment: @eggyal Would that still work if I was to create a subdomain and point it at the swf storage directory? (and then on the the embed page, use the subdomain instead of the local path). OR would it need to be a totally different domain?

Comment: No, browsers restrict security domains to one level beneath the appropriate [public suffix](http://publicsuffix.org/).  A subdomain would therefore be treated within the same security domain as the rest of the registered domain.

Comment: @eggyal What about if I had a totally different domain and then pointed it to the swf storage directory (and used that domain on the embed page instead of the local path)?...would this be fine OR would I actually need to store the swf on a different host aswell.

Comment: That sounds (to me) as though it should mitigate XSS risk.

Comment: @eggyal Cheers, but just to clarify in your opinion that would work even if it is actually hosted on the same host/file-system? (just using a totally different domain - purely for the swfs)

Comment: With regard to *mitigating* XSS risk, yes.  But enabling people to execute arbitrary SWF in others' browsers introduces other risks, especially if the Flash player/sandbox in those browsers contains exploitable vulnerabilities (as it often does).

Comment: @wvxvw It is a flash gaming site, where developers are allowed to submit there games (automatically). The primary audience is flash game developers - but of course that is not to stop someone abusing the way the system works (by submitting a malicious flash).

Answer (score 0):

If you allow a user to upload a flash movie, and you do not thoroughly check it for malicious code, you and everybody who watches the movie is doomed.

Sadly, flash essentially is a programming language with a long history of security failures. And the attacked system always is the users browser. That's why ad networks very heavily investigate if their customer do not intentionally send them malicious flash banners, but in the past they failed in an unacceptable number of cases.

I wouldn't do it if it were my users.

Comment: I don't know. Ask a flash security expert.

Comment: You can't. Vulnerabilities are, by their nature, all different; there is no universal way to detect them.